# Symfony 3 Extending Forms for Caching

Tags: php, forms, symfony, caching, redis

So I have a Symfony 3 app that is embedded in a website (.jsp). I have to redirect back to the webpage and not let it fall through to the view as it will display the app out of the website.

So in order to save the form states to give the user feedback on the redirect I have to cache the form errors and values into Redis and retrieve them again applying them back to the form to display.

I'm doing this at the top and bottom of every controller action that utilizes a form.

The problem is this is repeated code and bloats out my controllers. Is there anyway to extend Symfony form or maybe attach to a form event of some kind so that the following happens:

- Submit form.
- Check if form is valid.
- If form is not valid then the parent form class isValid method or form event caches to Redis.
- Perform redirect.
- When the form is created again check if it has an item in cache corresponding to it's name.
- Retrieve that cache and apply back to the form object.

Here is my current controller with the caching I want to abstract.

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 *
 * @Route("/signin", name="signin.user")
 */
public function signInAction(Request $request)
{
    // Instantiate the form with the Authentication entity.
    $authentication = new Authentication();
    $headers = $this->getAppHeaders();
    $form = $this->createForm(SignInFormType::class, $authentication, [
        'config' => $this->getCustomization(true)[$this->getActionName(true)]['form'] ?? [],
        'action' => '/apps/' . $headers['schemaId'] . '/' . $headers['schemaVersion'] . $this->generateUrl('signin.user'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ]);

    $redisService = $this->get('cache.redis_service');
    $serializer = $this->getSerializer();

    // Retrieve from cache and apply back to the form before purging cache.
    if ($cachedErrors = $redisService->hget('forms:' . $form->getName(), 'errors')) {
        $cachedErrors = $serializer->decode($cachedErrors, 'json');
        FormUtil::applyErrorsToForm($form, $cachedErrors);
        // Clear cache
        $redisService->hDel('forms:' . $form->getName(), 'errors');
    }

    // Handle the form request which also handle errors.
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // If the form is submitted and contains no errors then process.
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Try and perform authentication
            $authService = $this->get('core.authentication_service');

            if ($response = $authService->performLogin($authentication)) {
                return $response;
            }

            // User could not be authenticated return response.
            $formError = new FormError($authService->getResponseBody());
            $form->addError($formError);
        }

        if (count($form->getErrors())) {
            $this->flashMessage('danger', [
                'title' => 'There has been a problem',
                'template' => 'AppBundle:error:sign-in-error.html.twig'
            ]);
        }

        // Cache form errors before redirect.
        $redisService->hset('forms:' . $form->getName(), 'errors', FormUtil::getFormErrorsToSerialized($form));

        return $this->redirect($this->getFullPresencePath() . '/sign_in.page');
    }
    return $this->render(
        'AppBundle::signin.html.twig',
        [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'config' => $this->get('core.application_service')->getAppCustomization()
        ]
    );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)